# Object is greyed in viewport shadow

Tags: cycles-render-engine, 3d-view

So my cube or objects is greyed in viewport shadow

like this below
[image]

the scenes settings is cycles and gpu compute

anyone know how to fix this? i'm new to blender, i just followed tutorial from youtube(IanHubert). thanks

Comment: Can you upload your .blend file? https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: @Prime_Aqasix https://mega.nz/#F!9QJj2YaZ!75Ma8NnmVujh8sCEpPkb3g

Answer (score 0):

There could be a few things going on, but your Device in the Render Engine selection for cycles is greyed out. This could mean that your GPU is not able to be used (old or not supported) - or the preferences are not set correctly (Edit->Preferences->System).

After this is resolved, your lighting setup could also be an issue.

[image]